# SQL - Select max from a max(column) subset

Tags: sql, db2, max

I have a table defined like so:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2     Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6  

12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  yes      test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1 
12/5/2016 4:00:29pm  no       test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 4:00:29pm  no       test1   test1   test1   test1 
12/5/2016 3:59:59pm  yes      test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 3:59:59pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:59:29pm  yes      test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 3:59:29pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:58:59pm  yes      test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 3:58:59pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:58:29pm  yes      test    test    test    test  
12/5/2016 3:58:29pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:57:59pm  yes      test    test    test    test
12/5/2016 3:57:59pm  yes      test1   test1   test1   test1
```

As you can see, every 30 seconds a set of new records gets added to the table with the timestamp it had when the query ran and the variable Col2. In this case, it's only two sets (test, test1) for simplicity but it could be more. Col2 can actually be more than just yes/no but for simplicity's sake let's just say it can either be yes or no.

My question is how can I write a query that will return only the sets of records with the latest timestamp? One huge constraint to all this (which is what lead to me coming to stackoverflow) is that, when I write this query, I **have** to pull all records within the latest 90 second window for a reason I won't get into.

Currently what I have right now is the following:

```
SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, MAX(Col1)  
FROM table  
WHERE Col1 > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE - 90 SECONDS)  
GROUP BY Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
```

If all of the records in this sample table had 'yes' for Col2, then my above query would give me what I want and I would be done. However, the value can be yes or no.

This leads to the current issue I'm stuck at where, assuming the time is 4:01:00pm when the query runs, this returns the 2 'yes' records at 4:00:59pm and the 2 'no' records at 4:00:29pm. I want it to only return the 2 'yes' records, aka the records with the latest timestamp.

Because I call this query from a Java application, I currently have a function in place that accepts the result set from the above query as an argument, then loops through each record returned from the query and deletes all the duplicates (i.e. the 2 'no' records in this case). However, I was hoping rather than adding this logic, if there was a way I could just write the query such that it never returns the duplicate records outright.

**UPDATE:** So after trying to implement Matt's original solution, I ran into another issue. Matt's solution works if each set's (test, test1, etc) timestamp is the same. Unfortunately, they are not the same in our table, which means my table definition above is incorrect. See below for the updated table definition:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2     Col3    Col4  

12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  yes      test    test
12/5/2016 4:00:58pm  yes      test1   test1
12/5/2016 4:00:29pm  no       test    test  
12/5/2016 4:00:28pm  no       test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:59:59pm  yes      test    test 
12/5/2016 3:59:58pm  yes      test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:59:29pm  yes      test    test
12/5/2016 3:59:28pm  yes      test1   test1 
12/5/2016 3:58:59pm  yes      test    test 
12/5/2016 3:58:58pm  yes      test1   test1 
12/5/2016 3:58:29pm  yes      test    test  
12/5/2016 3:58:28pm  yes      test1   test1  
12/5/2016 3:57:59pm  yes      test    test
12/5/2016 3:57:58pm  yes      test1   test1
```

Col5/6 don't matter so deleted them for simplicity. So in this case, `t=1` returns the 4:00:59pm record, `t=2` returns the 4:00:58pm record, etc. Basically, each set (test,test1,test2,testn..) has its own unique timestamp. What this means is that for this query to work, I would need `t` to be less than or equal to a count of how many unique sets there are. See pseudo query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          Col2, Col3, Col4,
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) as Ranking
       FROM
          Table
       WHERE
          Col1 > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE - 90 SECONDS)
    ) t
WHERE
    t.Ranking <= [count of how many unique sets there are, in this case it would return 2(test,test1)]
```

Figuring out how to get that unique count is where I'm stuck at.

**UPDATE2:** Updating table definition again to show minimum columns needed for simplicity:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2    Col3

12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 4:00:58pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 4:00:57pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 4:00:56pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 4:00:29pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 4:00:28pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 4:00:27pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 4:00:26pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 3:59:59pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:59:58pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 3:59:57pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 3:59:56pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 3:59:29pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:59:28pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 3:59:27pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 3:59:26pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 3:58:59pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:58:58pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 3:58:57pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 3:58:56pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 3:58:29pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:58:28pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 3:58:27pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 3:58:26pm  test4   test4
12/5/2016 3:57:59pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 3:57:58pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 3:57:57pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 3:57:56pm  test4   test4
```

If the above is the table, I need the query to return the following:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2    Col3  

12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  test1   test1
12/5/2016 4:00:58pm  test2   test2
12/5/2016 4:00:57pm  test3   test3
12/5/2016 4:00:56pm  test4   test4
```

AKA, the latest timestamps for each unique occurrence of Col2/Col3. Using Matt's query as a base, if I set `t.Ranking = 1`, it will only return the following:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2     Col3

12/5/2016 4:00:59pm  test1   test1
```

`t.Ranking = 2` will return:

```
Col1(timestamp)      Col2     Col3

12/5/2016 4:00:58pm  test2   test2
```

and so on. In order for this query to work for me, `t.Ranking` needs to be a dynamic value that is always **less than or equal to** the number of unique occurrences of Col2 and Col3. So in my case, I would need `t.Ranking <=4` because there are 4 unique occurrences of Col2 and Col3 (test1, test2, test3, test4). If there were 5 unique occurrences of Col2/Col3, then t.Ranking would be less than or equal to 5 and so on.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          Col1, Col2, Col3,
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) as Ranking
       FROM
          Table
       WHERE
          Col1 > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE - 90 SECONDS)
    ) t
WHERE
    t.Ranking <= [count of how many unique occurrences of 
    Col2/Col3 there are, in this case it would return 
    4(test1,test2,test3,test4)]
```

Figuring out how to get that count is where I'm stuck at.

Comment: can you give an example of return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          COL1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) as Ranking
       FROM
          Table
       WHERE
          Col1 > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE - 90 SECONDS)
    ) t
WHERE
    t.Ranking = 1
```

From the sounds of things I am pretty sure you just need to create a ranking with DENSE_RANK() or RANK() so you can pick up the ties and then select when that = 1 to get the latest time stamp no matter how many records there are 1,2,100 etc.

Window Functions are definitely your friend for this type of operation and DB2 supports them. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_rankrows.html

***Edit*** it is a little unclear as to what you are wanting.  But perhaps you are wanting top 1 record per Col1,Col2 unique combination with ties?  If so use the same query only add a partition by clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          COL1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY
         CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END
         ,CASE WHEN col1 < col2 THEN col2 ELSE col1 END
      ORDER BY Col1 DESC) as Ranking
       FROM
          Table
       WHERE
          Col1 > (CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE - 90 SECONDS)
    ) t
WHERE
    t.Ranking = 1
```

Note the case statement in the partition by will make it so:

```
Col1      Col2
type     type1
type1    type
```

Will be considered as the same case.

If you don't want ties just change `DENSE_RANK()` to `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! This is a good start. Trying to implement my own version of this lead to 1 more issue. It's a lot easier for me to explain it by updating my question so please read my updated question.

Comment: @bscott I think I understand what you are looking for but it would be much easier say if you give the desired result in a tabular formula based on your example data.  Then to make sure I understand the nuance you are looking for perhaps you could provide 1 more test case.  thanks

Comment: @bscott see my update too perhaps it is what you are after

Comment: After re-reading my update, I agree I wasn't being clear as well. Please read my latest update in the question. Hopefully that should tell you what I'm looking for.

Comment: @bscott my edit that I did to may answer will handle that your updated question.  You need a Ranking PER Col1/col2 combination.  which just means you need to add a `PARTITION BY` clause that creates essentially a group by.  Note if the cases are determinate by column order meaning 'col1 = type, col2 = type1' and `col1 =  type1, col2 = type2` are supposed to be different cases then simply put `PARTITION BY Col1,Col2' if they are the same case use the case expression I included

Comment: Yes that was the issue. What you are saying is correct: `col2=type, col3=type1` and `col2=type1, col3=type2` are supposed to be different (unique) cases. col2 and col3 do not have to be the exact same value. Using `PARTITION BY Col2,Col3` rather than adding the `CASE WHEN` statements did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: @bscott your welcome glad to help.  Thanks for accepting the answer and if you wouldn't mind voting it up as well that would be great.  Glad you have what you need.